# How to protect camera circuit

Tags: attacks

We have a building with n cameras connected to a Digital Video Recorder that has been attacked, this DVR provides a web server in port 90 that can be accessed from the internet. All the system were recovered by using backups, DVR Firmware could not be updated since manufacturer deprecated it in 2014. How is it possible to add an extra layer of protection to this stack without loosing the connectivity to the web server from the internet?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the connections are HTTP based, set up a web server (e.g. nginx / Apache) as a reverse proxy in front of the DVR, and require inbound connections to that web server to be authenticated over HTTPS with a client certificate. This way the DVR is never directly routed to the internet.

If you require access to other protocols, e.g. RTSP for video, I'd suggest creating an isolated network that contains the DVR and cameras, then setting up a VPN endpoint so that you can remotely access the DVR environment.

Comment: Regarding the second idea, setting up a VPN won't allow me to use the HTTP application from internet, right? thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AlejandroMorán You'd VPN into the network and then access the HTTP application through a browser like you normally would.

Comment: And seriously consider updating off a platform that is now 4 years out of support.  This answer is a good idea, which I've upvoted, but you're really putting a bandage on a larger problem and just enabling it to limp along longer.

Comment: VPN could also be replaced with SSH port forwarding. A bit more of a lightweight setup if you already have Linux machines.

Comment: @korockinout13 SSH forwarding is more ad-hoc, though, and makes things more awkward if you're trying to connect from a mobile platform.

Comment: @baldPrussian Agreed. This answer was written in direct answer to the question. Upgrading is the best path if possible, but if business requirements are prohibitive then a secure way to isolate the existing system is the next best thing.

Comment: @baldPrussian Yes for sure updating is the best idea but it depends on budget, and this depends on the local goverment (Spain in this case) and unfortunately there is no more budget assigned to this. Thank you guys for all your contribution.

Comment: @korockinout13 There is no machines at this time, DVR is directly connected to the router, I thought about using a Raspberry Pi since there's no more budget, do you think it is a good idea to use it to setup an VPN?

Comment: @AlejandroMorán Don't use a Pi. It's not designed to be stable for long periods of time. Grab yourself a router (e.g. Netgear R7000) and install AdvancedTomato on it, and then configure the VPN via that. You'll thank me later for the stability and ease of setup.

Comment: @Polynomial thanks a lot, I've been reading about that router and it's VPN configuration, seems to be a good and cheap solution too.

Comment: While waiting for your new router to arrive, consider port forwarding a random high numbered external port to port 90 to keep the DVR system off shodan.io

Answer (score 3):

You can always set up a **VPN** server on your local network so that any user who wants to watch the video , has to be connected and authenticated.
This way you will be able to access the camera as if you were on the LAN.